# Unwanted "Expand" link won't go away. Can't trace source. display:none; not working. (Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

As seen on any product at alcapparel.com:

http://www.alcapparel.com/shop/clothing/looter-crop-tee/

As you can see the word "Expand" is located in the upper left of the product image. I've reinstalled the YITH WooCommerce Magnifier plugin, they reportedly patched it two days ago, and I can't find the source of the word anywhere in the files. I've also tried hiding it with

```
    .pp_expand {display: none !important;}
```

but that doesn't work either.

I'm quite baffled. Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:**
Use this CSS to forcefully hide it. Put it in any .css file

```
.yith_magnifier_mousetrap a {
display:none !important;
}
```

**Old Answer:**

HTML of the the link can be traced to

```
<a style="display: inline;" title="Expand the image" class="pp_expand" href="#">Expand</a>
```

Change this to

```
<a style="display: none;" title="Expand the image" class="pp_expand" href="#">Expand</a>
```

If you can't trace the source of this link/file, it is likely coming from a javascript or from a plugin you are using.

Comment: I can't change 

        display: inline;

because I can't find the source, and when I try to overwrite with 

        display: none;

in the css of the child theme, wordpress, and in the plugin, nothing is helping.

Comment: @AdamThomson see my update answer. You can forcefully hide it using targetted css but remember it can affect other areas as well. I have check it safe here on this page but  you can make it more targetted so it does not affect other areas.